# How to integrate ACS in iOS thru Facebook App?

Tags: ios, facebook, acs

I have a Windows Azure ACS service setup and configured to use Facebook as the identity provider.  Now I want my iOS client to integrate with this authN flow, I want my user can sign in using their facebook account and ACS can issue a SWT token back to my user.  Question is: I saw that if I have Facebook App Installed in my iPhone, some iOS apps can redirect user to their facebook iOS app for sign in then back to their own app instead of a webpage,  Can I really do that with ACS? if so any pointers in doing so?

Thanks alot